# Invariant subspace of group representation

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions, invariant-subspace

Let $G:=S_n$ and let $V:=k^n$.

Suppose characteristic of $k$ does not divide $n$.

Define $U:=\{(a_,...,a_n \mid \sum a_i=0\}$

If $\exists$ subspace $U' \subseteq U$ s.t.

$\{e\} \neq U'$ and $gU' \subseteq U'$ $\forall g \in S_n$,

Then $U'=U$.

So $\subseteq$ is clear,

Pick $0 \neq \alpha \in U$, then $\alpha = (a_1,...a_n)$

Since characteristic of $k$ does not divide $n$, we know all entries cannot be equal, furthermore we know all entries cannot be zero and. Where do I go from here to ensure $\alpha \in U'$ ? i.e., $U$ has no nontrivial proper invariant subspaces.

Comment: The characteristic of $k$ has nothing to do with $\alpha$ having equal or different entries. In fact, for any characteristic, $(1,\dots, 1)\in k^n$. You will probably need the characteristic or $k$ to apply Schur's lemma (or any of its corolaries).

Comment: any idea on how to do this then lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutation module of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212025/permutation-module-of-s-n) (see the most voted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside $k^n$ we have two invariant subspaces that are easy to write down: $U$ and $V = \langle (1,1,1, \dots,1) \rangle$.  If $p|n$ then $V \subset U$, and if not then they intersect trivially and $U \oplus V = k^n$.

Claim:  These are the only two invariant proper subspaces in $k^n$.

Let's prove it by induction on $n$, for $n=2$ it is easy to check directly (with the slight caveat that $U=V$ if we are in characteristic $2$ and $n=2$).

Suppose $W$ is another invariant subspace, and lets take $v \in W$ to be a vector where not all its coordinates are equal (if no such vector exists $W=V$).  By using the $S_n$ action to flip two unequal coordinates and subtracting what we get from $v$, we obtain a new non-zero vector $v'\in W$ that has at least one coordinate equal to zero.  By permuting the coordinates, we can assume that the last coordinate is zero.

Hence we have found a vector $v' \subset W \cap k^{n-1}$ for the standard embedding of $k^{n-1}$ in $k^n$.  This intersection $W \cap k^{n-1}$ is a non-empty $S_{n-1}$ invariant subspace of $k^{n-1}$. Hence by induction we know it must be either the space where the sum of the coordinates is zero, the $1$-dimensional invariant subspace, or all of $k^{n-1}$.

If $W \cap k^{n-1} = k^{n-1}$ then it contains the vector $(1,0, \dots)$, and its $S_n$ orbits clearly span $k^n$ so $W$ must be all of $k^{n}$.

If $W \cap k^{n-1}$ is the space where the sum of the coordinates is zero it contains $(1,-1, 0, \dots, 0)$, and the $S_n$-orbit of that spans $U$. Hence $W$ must contain $U$, so $W = U$ or $W = k^n$ as $U$ has codimension 1.

If $W \cap k^{n-1}$ is the one dimensional subspace spanned by $(1,1,\dots, 1, 0)$.  By permuting the coordinates, $(0,1,1\dots 1)$ is also in $W$ and by subtracting $(1, 0,0, \dots -1)$ is in $W$.  Again, the $S_n$ orbit of this spans all of $U$ so $W = U$ or $W = k^n$.