# Split 3D representation of S3 in irreducible components

Tags: representation-theory

I saw from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220579/proving-the-3-dimensional-representation-of-s3-is-reducible) that you can prove that the 3d representation of S3 is reducible.

What if I want to split this representation in a sum of irreducible representation?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by "the 3d representation" you mean the representation afforded by $S_3$ acting on $\mathbb R^3$ by permuting components. Counting fixpoints shows that the character of this representation is $3$ at the identity, $1$ at transpositions and $0$ at $2$-cycles. Then forming scalar products with the rows of [the character table of $S_3$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group%3aS3#Character_table) shows that this representation is the sum of the trivial representation and [the two-dimensional irreducible representation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group%3aS3).