# Showing that $\mathbb{F}^n = \mathrm{span}\{\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\}\oplus \mathrm{span}\{\sum_{i=1}^nc_ie_i\mid \sum_{i=1}^nc_i = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $\mathbb{F}^n$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$ with a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$. I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{F}^n = \mathrm{span}\{\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\}\oplus \mathrm{span}\{\sum_{i=1}^nc_ie_i\mid \sum_{i=1}^nc_i = 0\}$ as a part a direct proof (as suggested by Qiaochu) for the claim discussed here: [Irreducibility of the standard representation of $S_n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137303/irreducibility-of-the-standard-representation-of-s-n) . Currently, I'm stuck at the following: Let $v \in \mathbb{F}^n, v = \sum_{i=1}^nc_ie_i, c_i\in \mathbb{F},i=1,\dots,n$. Then if $v = \sum_{i=1}^nd_ie_i + \beta\sum_{i=1}^ne_i$ with $d_1,\dots,d_n, \beta \in \mathbb{F}, \sum_{i=1}^nd_i = 0$, we have by the linear independence of $e_1,\dots,e_n$ that $c_i = d_i + \beta, \forall i = 1,\dots,n$. And I'm not really sure how to proceed onwards from here. The equation implies that $c_i - d_i = c_j - d_j, \forall i, j = 1,\dots,n$, which feels a bit shady to me.

Comment: Consider $v = \sum \alpha_i e_i = \alpha (\sum e_i) + \sum (\alpha_i - \alpha) e_i,$ where $\alpha = \sum \alpha_i,$ this shows that $\mathbf{F}^n$ is a sum of the two subspaces; to show the sum is direct, simply note $\alpha \sum e_i = \sum c_i e_i$ (note that the second summand is already a subspace so it is its own span) implies that $\alpha = c_i$ for each $i$ and therefore $n \alpha = 0,$ so $c_i = \alpha = 0.$

Comment: By the way, the gist of the proof is that the "main diagonal" (i.e. $\langle \mathbf{1} \rangle,$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of 1s) is orthogonal to the subspace of "contrasts" (i.e. $\{\sum c_i e_i \mid \sum c_i = 0\}$). This result is thoroughly used in statistics and all of applied mathematics where the main diagonal represents averages while contrasts represent changes between different quantities (i.e. comparisons).

Comment: @WilliamM. If $v = \sum\alpha_ie_i$ and $\alpha = \sum\alpha_i$, then isn't $\sum(\alpha_i - \alpha) = (\sum\alpha_i) - n\alpha = -(n - 1)\alpha$, which is zero iff $n = 1$ or the coefficients of $v$ already satisfy the property $\sum\alpha_i = 0$ of the second subspace?

Comment: I think you are right and $\alpha$ is then the average, that is $\alpha = \frac{1}{n} \sum \alpha_i,$ then $\sum (\alpha_i - \alpha) = 0.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Yeah, this makes sense! A bit off-topic, but do you happen to know some good material on the "subspace of contrasts"? It seems interesting.

Comment: It appears a lot in the study of linear regression. More precisely, you'd need to find a theoretical book that treats it as projection onto subspaces. The two that come to mind are of the New Zelander statistician George Seber's _Linear Regression Analysis_ and the Japanese Takeuchi's (et al) _Foundations of Multivariate [Statistical] Analysis. A unified approach by means of projections onto linear subspaces._ By the way, a lot of authors/books treat linear regression as a calculus problem (minimise some quadratic form). This kills intuition in my opinion.

Comment: Might be easier to think first in terms of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $x = (x-{ e^T x \over e^T x} e ) + { e^T x \over e^T x} e $.